# How to add dual quotation marks in string using StreamWriter

Tags: c#, .net

```
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
        { 
            using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(fs))
        {
            tw.WriteLine("<xpml><page quantity='0' pitch='76.2 mm'></xpml>SIZE 76.2 mm, 76.2 mm");
            tw.WriteLine("DIRECTION 0,0");
            tw.WriteLine("REFERENCE 0,0");
            tw.WriteLine("OFFSET 0 mm");
            tw.WriteLine("SET PEEL OFF");
            tw.WriteLine("SET CUTTER OFF");
            tw.WriteLine("<xpml></page></xpml><xpml><page quantity='1' pitch='76.2 mm'></xpml>SET TEAR ON");
            tw.WriteLine("CLS");
            tw.WriteLine("CODEPAGE 1252");
            tw.WriteLine("TEXT 579,370,&quot;ROMAN.TTF&quot;,180,1,12,&quot;Party Name:&quot;");
            tw.WriteLine("BARCODE 527,546,&quot;128M&quot;,102,0,180,3,6,&quot;!104CR!0991234567890123445r&quot;");
            tw.WriteLine("TEXT 451,439,'ROMAN.TTF',180,1,12,'CR1234567890123445'");
            tw.WriteLine("TEXT 579,329,'ROMAN.TTF',180,1,12,'Order no:'");
            tw.WriteLine("TEXT 579,289,'ROMAN.TTF',180,1,12,'Ref No:'");
            tw.WriteLine("TEXT 579,249,'0',180,13,10,'Date:'");
            tw.WriteLine("TEXT 579,209,'ROMAN.TTF',180,1,12,'W X H:'");
            tw.WriteLine("TEXT 579,169,'ROMAN.TTF',180,1,12,'Prd Ty:'");
            tw.WriteLine("TEXT 579,128,'ROMAN.TTF',180,1,12,'Remarks:'");
            tw.WriteLine("TEXT 392,370,'ROMAN.TTF',180,1,12,'AMI Distributors'");
            tw.WriteLine("TEXT 439,329,'ROMAN.TTF',180,1,12,'"+order_no+"'");
            tw.WriteLine("TEXT 460,289,'ROMAN.TTF',180,1,12,'"+o_ref+"'");
            tw.WriteLine("TEXT 497,249,'0',180,13,10,'"+ttime+"'");
            tw.WriteLine("TEXT 477,209,'ROMAN.TTF',180,1,12,'"+w+""+u+" X "+h+""+u+"'");
            tw.WriteLine("TEXT 472,169,'ROMAN.TTF',180,1,12,'"+pro+"'");
            tw.WriteLine("TEXT 436,128,'ROMAN.TTF',180,1,12,'"+oprating+"'");
            tw.WriteLine("PRINT 1,1");
            tw.WriteLine("<xpml></page></xpml><xpml><end/></xpml>");

            }
        }
```

tw.WriteLine("TEXT 460,289,**'ROMAN.TTF'**,180,1,12,'"+o_ref+"'");

in text file print this **'ROMAN.TTF'** and won't in file with dual quotation  like this **"ROMAN.TTF"**

Comment: One not-related-to-the-question comment: you can instantiate the `StreamWriter` variable from the path directly. That is: rather than the two `using` statements you can have just one defined with `using (StreamWriter tw = new StreamWriter(path))`.

Comment: Regarding your question, you can escape double quotes in C# with `\"`. &quot; is not C#, but HTML.

Comment: Is this supposed to output valid XML?

Comment: String path = @"c:\PRN File\myFile.PRN";   this is the path where i store and create my file and

Comment: Although logically, the target format will have also something to say. In some cases, if you write unescaped quotes, it might be a problem. The answer to your question is clear: escape the quotes where required (i.e., replace the &quot; bits with the C# escaped version). The (continuation) advice would be: analyse the exact situation properly to make sure that you do want unescaped quotes to be outputted at all.

Comment: thanks buddy i got my ans using this \"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
\"
```

in your string (like this: `"text \"quotedtext\" more text"`) to insert a double quotation mark.
Using a verbatim string (`@"your string text"`) you can simply use two double quotation marks like this `""` to insert a double quotation mark.
I hope i didnt confuse you too much with that many quotation marks...

Comment: You might want to try to use code [formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to help alleviate the confusion. Clarifying what the \ character actually is and does would be even better!

Comment: I have changed the quotes, hope it looks better now :)